# May I add 2GB of RAM in a HP dc7900 MT

Tags: memory, dual-channel

I currently have 2GB of RAM with this schema:

```
Slot 0: 1GB (Channel 1)
Slot 1: N/A (Channel 2)
Slot 2: 1GB (Channel 1)
Slot 3: N/A (Channel 2)
```

May I add a 2GB of RAM in `Slot 1` even if it's in Dual-Channel? (2GB is not enough for `.NET` and Web programmation!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  They must be added in like pairs to take advantage of Dual Channel Mode.  dual Channel Mode will provide a performnce improvement.

As RAM is relatively inexpensive, 2X2GB might be a better choice.

Note that 4GB is normally max if using a 32Bit OS.

If you have 2X1GB DIMMs now, adding one 2GB DIMMM will give you 4GB total.  That may report as less depending on things like Integrated Video and other factors

[Kingston info](http://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search/Default.aspx?DeviceType=2&Mfr=HEW&Line=Business%20Desktop&Model=50114)

Comment: May I have like `1GB, 2GB, 1GB, nothing` or I really need to put `1GB, 1GB, 1GB, 1GB` 'cause Dual-Channel isn't my first need!

Comment: You may add a 2GB DIMM for a total of 4GB

Comment: I'll get 4GB if I add a 2GB DIMM?

Answer (score 0):

Add 2Gb in slot 0 and 1Gb in slot 3 and 1Gb in slot 4. You will have dual channel (both channels will have equal amount of RAM) and 4 Gb in total.